# How do I place a text object 90% down my page?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a text object placed in the middle of my page horizontally. I'm wanting to place it 90% down my page. So if you were looking at my page, it would be a little above the bottom. I would use `margin: 330px;` but I am pretty sure it will differ for ever user as they use different resolutions. Here is my code, if someone can help

```
HTML:      
  <div id="home">
    <p>Read More</p>
  </div>

CSS:
  #home {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #home p {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 330px;
  }
```

Comment: `margin-bottom: 10%;` should work, no?

Comment: @Gendarme That just placed it in the middle of the page sadly.

Comment: `position: absolute; bottom: 10px;`

Comment: oh, for that to work, you  will also need `position: relative` on #home

Comment: The solutions depends on many variables. Is it going to have content after text object?

Comment: @2pha So I just tried what you suggested and the text went towards the bottom but making the position absolute, the text-align center I had just stopped working. I tried to add a text-align: center directly onto the text object but that didn't work.

Comment: @SteelZK wrap it into a parent div

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo The text doesn't have content under it in the same dir. But I have it where you scroll down, it enters a new dir which displays text and such.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bvFw5zX

Answer (score 1):

You can set your body to 100%, then use a wrapper div to house all the content above the home dive. The make the wrapper div 90% less the font size.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#main_content {
  min-height: calc(90% - 60px);
  /* Make space for the font size */
}

#home {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#home p {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: teal;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_content">
</div>
<div id="home">
  <p>Read More</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the container a flexbox, and align the heading to the bottom using `margin-top: auto`. To bring it up from the bottom a bit add a value for `margin-bottom` (10% in the example). Use media queries if you want to be very precise with placement across screen sizes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#home {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#home p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #000;
  margin: auto 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="home">
  <p>Read More</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work as it should for every user you need to use relative lengths.
To place it "90% down" your page you can use :

```
margin-top: 90vh;
```

Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) you can find what you're looking for there. 
Good Luck,